# How to debug error message from luaotfload-database.lua

Tags: errors, luatex, texlive, debugging

I am beginning to think it was a really bad idea to update to TeXLive 2013. Since this update almost none of my old documents compile any longer. Does anyone have any idea what LuaLaTeX is trying to do when giving this error:

```
! LuaTeX error ...texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:890: 
attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' (a nil value).
<to be read again> 
\f 
l.133
```

*i.e,* where do I start the debugging process this time?

Comment: This happens when for a given font family there are members of the same style that come with and without design size information.

Fixed in the dev version a while ago: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/commit/3cbbd94c24c6d3a3b7b6b0cda3ed2175b84373ad

Comment: Okey, so in other words there isn't much I can do?

Comment: You could try using the corrected file from that commit: https://raw.github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/3cbbd94c24c6d3a3b7b6b0cda3ed2175b84373ad/luaotfload-database.lua but **backup the existing file** before you do so. It’s been a while and I don’t quite remember if this is still compatible with the version on CTAN.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved by updating luaotfload.